# I am getting an error as "Unknown table" error?

Tags: mysql

I have declared a a table as "m" still the query is giving me an arror. Here is the query:

```
select m.id AS id,
       m.product_id AS product_id,
       m.status AS `status`,
       m.pmatch AS pmatch,
       m.p_offset AS p_offset,
       m.smatch AS smatch,
       m.s_offset AS s_offset,
       m.tmatch AS tmatch,
       m.t_offset AS t_offset,
       m.txt1hex AS txt1hex,
       m.txt2hex AS txt2hex,
       m.txt3hex AS txt3hex,
       m.http_host AS http_host,
       m.http_uri AS http_uri,
       m.http_user_agent AS http_user_agent,
       m.http_cookie AS http_cookie,
       m.direction AS direction,
       m.trans AS trans,
       m.conn AS conn,
       m.min_pl_len AS min_pl_len,
       m.max_pl_len AS max_pl_len,
       m.stream_off AS stream_off,
       m.packet_num AS packet_num,
       m.sip AS sip,
       m.sp AS sp,
       m.dip AS dip,
       m.dp AS dp,
       m.stage AS stage,
       m.func_index AS func_index,
       m.usage AS usage,
       m.comments AS comments,
       m.created AS created,
       m.createdby AS createdby,
       m.updated AS updated,
       m.updatedby AS updatedby
from   sp_mip_rule m
where  exists(select 1 AS 1
              from vw_extr_active_socnet_product p
              where ((p.id = sp_mip_rule.product_id) and (sp_mip_rule.status = 1) ))
```

Comment: In this line `m.stream_off\` AS stream_off,` is the backtick *meant* to be there?

Comment: No its not, And i corrected it. Its still not working

Comment: Why are you bothering to alias the table? Also, if you write your statement out on many lines, the MySQL message might give you a better hint about where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<1> You have an unmatched quote:

```
m.stream_off` AS stream_off
```

<2> `USAGE` is a reserved word. You need to quote it:

```
m.usage AS `usage`
```

<3> If you want to use `1` as column alias, you need to quote it:

```
select 1 AS '1'
```

... or:

```
select 1 AS `1`
```

... though of course it's not really necessary to alias a column with its own name.

I suggest you write your SQL code in several lines and use an editor with syntax highlighting. That makes it easier to spot this kind of errors.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have aliased the table as `m` in the `FROM` clause, *I think* you must also refer to it as `m` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select m.id AS id,abunchofotherstuff
from sp_mip_rule m
where exists(select 1 AS 1 from vw_extr_active_socnet_product p where ((p.id = m.product_id) and (m.status = 1) ))
```

Comment: It is referenced as m in where clause where ((p.id = m.product_id) and (m.status = 1)

Comment: @vincy You mean that was the problem? Looking at your code I still see `(p.id = sp_mip_rule.product_id) and (sp_mip_rule.status = 1)` in the `WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

The parens are off in your WHERE clause. You've got the `m.status=1` buried inside the exists. I think you want that check outside of the exists.

```
...
where m.status = 1 
    and exists(select 1 from vw_extr_active_socnet_product p where p.id = m.product_id)
```

Comment: @vincy: If one of the answers provided solved your problem, please accept it. If not, post your solution as an answer so the question has some closure.